# Meteor SSR require().addStyle is not function

Tags: typescript, meteor, server-side-rendering

I am trying to implement server side rendering into existing project.
Here is my client side ;

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  if (window.$ == undefined || window.jquery == undefined || window.jQuery == undefined) {
    window.$ = window.jquery = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
    import("jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js");
  }

  const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  };

  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    onPageLoad(() => {
      ReactDOM.hydrate(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById("react-target"));
    });
  }
});
```

Here is my server side;

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  onPageLoad((sink) => {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

      const hash = (word: string) => {
        const h: any = 0xdeadbeef11Bc7Aa1fF21;
        for (let i = 0, h; i < word.length; i++) h = Math.imul(h! ^ word.charCodeAt(i), 2611039521);
        return (h ^ h >>> 16) >>> 0;
      };

      const persistedState = jwt.verify(localStorage.getItem("state"), "trlogic", (err: any, decoded: any) => {
        try {
          if (decoded) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("state")) {
              const { user } = decoded;
              if (hash(JSON.stringify({ user })).toString() !== localStorage.getItem("userToken")!.toString()) {
              }
              return { user };
            }
            return undefined;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      });
      const context = {};
      const store = createStore(AppReducer, persistedState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

      const AppRouter = (props: any) => {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={props!.location} context={context}>
              <Router history={history}>
                <App />
              </Router>
            </StaticRouter>
          </Provider>
        );
      };

      const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
      const html = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(
        <AppRouter location={sink.request!.url} />,
      ));

      sink.renderIntoElementById!("react-target", html);
      const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
      sink.appendToHead!(helmet.meta.toString());
      sink.appendToHead!(helmet.title.toString());
      sink.appendToHead!(sheet.getStyleTags());
    }
  });
}
```

and I am getting this error,

```
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR) /Users/murat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1szhckc.34ej++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280 W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR)                         ^ W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR)
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR) TypeError: require(...).addStyles is not a function
```

Btw, the project is using Typescript

edit:
The full error code is that

```
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR) /Users/murat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.2.0.0.1szhckc.34ej++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR)
W20210309-14:48:24.725(3)? (STDERR) TypeError: require(...).addStyles is not a function
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at module (/Users/murat/Documents/TRLogic/formicabox/formicabox-client/service/formicabox-ui/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:53006:44)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/murat/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.16.0.hebza9.gspxj++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at module (imports/router/AppRouter/AppRouter.tsx:1:61)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/murat/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.16.0.hebza9.gspxj++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at module (imports/components/App.tsx:1:53)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210309-14:48:24.726(3)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210309-14:48:24.731(3)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/murat/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.16.0.hebza9.gspxj++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20210309-14:48:24.731(3)? (STDERR)     at module (server/main.tsx:1:27)
W20210309-14:48:24.731(3)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210309-14:48:24.731(3)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210309-14:48:24.731(3)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21)
W20210309-14:48:24.731(3)? (STDERR)     at /Users/murat/Documents/TRLogic/formicabox/formicabox-client/service/formicabox-ui/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:60911:15
W20210309-14:48:24.731(3)? (STDERR)     at /Users/murat/Documents/TRLogic/formicabox/formicabox-client/service/formicabox-ui/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:401:38
W20210309-14:48:24.732(3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20210309-14:48:24.732(3)? (STDERR)     at /Users/murat/Documents/TRLogic/formicabox/formicabox-client/service/formicabox-ui/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:226:21
W20210309-14:48:24.732(3)? (STDERR)     at /Users/murat/Documents/TRLogic/formicabox/formicabox-client/service/formicabox-ui/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:464:7
W20210309-14:48:24.732(3)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/murat/Documents/TRLogic/formicabox/formicabox-client/service/formicabox-ui/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:280:14)
```

I could not find any source to solve that. It seems that program can't render css or style files.

Comment: Hello Murat and welcome to SO. Please can you edit your question, adding **all** relevant information to the question (as text) rather than in images? If the question doesn't stand-alone without reference to these images, then you won't get a very good reception. Stackoverflow should be easily searchable. What will this question contribute to the next person facing the same problem as you? Will they be able to find it?

Comment: `addStyles` doesn't appear in your code, so the full stack trace of the error is important here. There should have been more to the error that what you show here. Could you add the rest?